# $A + B = \{\,x + y \mid x ∈ A,\, y ∈ B\,\}$ is closed in $ [0,\infty)$ for any closed $A, B \subseteq [0,∞)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $A, B$ are closed subsets of $[0,∞)$, then
$$A + B = \{\,x + y \mid x ∈ A,\, y ∈ B\,\}$$
is closed in $ [0,\infty)$.

If $A ,B$ are closed sets in $\mathbb R$ , then i know counterexamples but considering only non negative reals ,i can't able to get a counterexample which doesn't implies it must be true.

So i want to prove or disprove , I know it is not true in genral but under this particular situation i want to know it is TRUE /FALSE

Comment: In case you didn't see my reply to your comment beneath my (now deleted) answer, you were quite right, my answer was quite wrong. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a sequence $(x_n)\subseteq A+B$ convergent to $x\in [0,\infty)$. We want to show that $x\in A+B$.

It follows that $x_n=a_n+b_n$ for some sequences $(a_n)\subseteq A$ and $(b_n)\subseteq B$. Since $A,B$ are subsets of $[0,\infty)$ then $$0\leq a_n\leq x_n$$
$$0\leq b_n\leq x_n$$

In particular, since $x_n$ is bounded then so are $a_n$ and $b_n$ (this is exactly the place where the proof would fail for whole $\mathbb{R}$ case). Therefore they have convergent subsequences, say $a_{n_k}$ and $b_{n_k}$ (we can choose indexes in such a way that they coincide). It follows that

$$x=\lim_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n=\lim_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{n_k}= \lim_{k=0}^{\infty}\big(a_{n_k}+b_{n_k}\big)=\lim_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{n_k}+\lim_{k=0}^{\infty}b_{n_k}\in A+B$$

the last "$\in$" because $A,B$ are closed.

Comment: We don't know anything about uniqueness of subsequential limit of $a_{n_{k}}$ and $b_{n_{k}} $. Is it a problem? To uniqueness of x?

Comment: @CloudJR You mean that these limits depend on the choice of subsequences? Yes, but it doesn't matter. The only important thing is that they belong to $A,B$ respectively and their sum is $x$. Note that the choice of whole $(a_n), (b_n)$ sequences is not unique as well. In particular if $A=B=[0,\infty)$ then there's a lot of different choices.

Comment: Is it possible to choose indices such that it coincides? if $a_{n_k}$ are odd terms and $b_{n_k}$ are even terms then?

Comment: @CloudJR yes because you first take a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ and then you choose $b$ as a subsequence of $x_{n_k}$ rather then whole $x_n$. Finally you adjust indexes of (already convergent) $a_{n_k}$. In other words you **don't** choose $a_{n_k}$ and $b_{n_k}$ independently.

Comment: thankyou ...........

Answer (score 5):

If $A$ and $B$ are compact, $A + B$ is compact because it is the image of the compact set $A \times B$ under the continuous function $(a,b) \mapsto a+b$.

If $A$ and $B$ are closed subsets of $[0,\infty)$, then for all $N > 0$ we have 
$$(A + B) \cap [0, N] = ((A \cap [0,N]) + (B \cap [0,N])) \cap [0,N]$$ which is closed, therefore $A + B$ is closed.

Comment: Please  explain your argument in final step...you prove for all N>0, $(A + B) \cap [0, N]$ is closed .Then how A+B is cosed? What is argument here... Please explain thanks

Comment: If $x < N$, and $S \subseteq [0,\infty)$, $x \in \overline{S}$ iff $x \in \overline{S \cap [0,N]}$.  This is because a sequence $s_n$ converging to $x$ must be $< N$ eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the compactification $X = [0,+\infty]$. We can extend the addition function to $X \times X$ by defining $+\infty + x = x + +\infty = +\infty$ for all $x \in X$, and one can check this is still continuous as a map $p$ from $X \times X \to X$. Then, if $A,B \subseteq [0,+\infty)$ are closed, then their closures in $X$ are either $A$ resp $B$ or $A \cup \{+\infty\}$ or $B \cup \{+\infty\}$ respectively, depending on whether $A$ and $B$ were bounded or not.

In either case $p[\overline{A} \times \overline{B}]$ is compact hence closed in $X$ and so $A + B = p[\overline{A} \times \overline{B}] \cap [0,+\infty)$ is also closed in $[0,+\infty)$.